# Eclipse, code completion doesn't work for android api 21 codes

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm still using `Eclipse` for programming android and I've added 'api-21' and it's support libraries. But in XML editor of `values-21/styles.xml` I can't find `api-21` recently added items such as `<item name="colorPrimary"></item>` and so on and I have to write them buy myself! (previous items such as `<item name="android:background"></item>` are available)

Is it OK or I can do some tricks? and also where can I find all **new** style items?

Comment: Are you **targetting** API Level 21 or later?

Comment: @der-golem Yes I do!